# divide and conque binary search in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to make a divide and conquer version of binary search, but one that divides the array to two subarrays and search similar to merging in merge sort, the reason I want to do that becuase I want to use it in cilk, but I have to make it that way.
Here is the code I wrote, which seems to have something wrong with it as its returning -1 to valid key values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "BinarySearch.h"

int main () {
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int index = binarySearch(a, 0, 9, 7);
    printf("%i", index);

    return 0;
}

int binarySearch (int* A, int first, int last, int key) {
    if (last < first)
        return -1;
    else {
        int mid = (last + first) / 2;

        if (A[mid] == key)
            return mid;

        int x, y;
        x = binarySearch(A, first, mid - 1, key);
        y = binarySearch(A, mid + 1, last, key);

        if (x == -1 && y == -1)
            return -1;
        else if (x == -1 && y != -1)
            return y;
        else
            return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the next step is to use the debugger (or lots of print statements) to trace the flow of your program, to determine where its behaviour diverges from what you expect.

Comment: When you're always searching both halves, it's not divide and conquer, you're scanning the entire array if the key isn't present.

Comment: Show us your exact test cases?

Comment: I don't think that was copied from code that compiles ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, `99` doesn't exist in your array. The result is correct. You probably just messed up the parameters - the first one is the array, the next two represent the range of the search, the fourth one is what you're looking for. A correct call would be:

```
int index = binarySearch(A, 0, 10, 4);
```

Also, this

```
int* A = &a[0];
```

is useless, you can simply use `a` as arrays decay to pointers:

```
int index = binarySearch(a, 0, 7, 99);  // a instead of A
```

Also - a **binary search** takes into account the fact that the array is sorted. If your key is lower than the middle value, why bother searching to the right - it's guaranteed you won't find it there.

What you're doing is `O(n)`, as opposed to a `O(log(n))` binary search solution.

Comment: Not really, the search in the right half will at some point call `binarySearch(A,10,10,4);`.

Comment: It seems this was the problem, the invalid parameters passed
Thanks Luchian and everybody

Answer (score 1):

For any one still looking for solutions, [I found this made by `ankzcode`](http://ankzcode.blogspot.in/2012/11/find-minimum-without-linear-search.html).

It finds the minimum value in an array without linear search, using divide and conquer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findMin(int a[], int l,int h)
{
    int pivot = (l + h) / 2;
    int minl=-1, minh = -1;

    if ( (pivot - l ) > 1) 
    {
        minl = findMin(a, l, pivot);
    }
    else 
    {
        minl = (a[l] > a[pivot])?a[pivot]:a[l];
    }
    if ( (h - pivot ) > 1) 
    {
        minh = findMin(a, pivot, h);
    }
    else 
    {
        minh = (a[l] > a[pivot])?a[pivot]:a[l];
    }

    return (minl>minh)?minh:minl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={5,2,9,10,3};
    printf("%d\n",findMin(a, 0, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you gave the key 99,which is not in array,So its obvious the code return -1.